# Scrolling a ScrollView page-by-page

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm trying to scroll a `ScrollView` in a loop and do something between the scrolls until it reaches the bottom. Ideally, I would like to scroll it "page-by-page" to minimize the number of `scrollBy` invocations and to avoid showing the same content twice.

I tried something like this:

```kotlin
var afterScrollY: Int

val scrollBy = scrollView.height

do {
    val beforeScrollY = scrollView.scrollY

    // This is why I need to scroll "page-by-page" instead of going straight to the bottom
    doSomethingAtCurrentScrollPosition()

    scrollView.scrollBy(0, scrollBy)
    afterScrollY = scrollView.scrollY
} while (afterScrollY != beforeScrollY)
```

but it looks like scrolling by the `ScrollView`'s height doesn't do exactly what I want.

[image: Expected and actual behavior]

My layout is very simple and doesn't contain any margins or paddings:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure if you aware of https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SnapHelper

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang but don't want to snap the `ScrollView`'s position to the views inside it. I thought maybe there is a better property than `height` to find the right number of pixels to scroll by. For context: my goal is to take a screenshot of the whole `ScrollView`'s content.